# What is the difference (pros and cons) to use Load balancer vs using multiple connection string in xcc for Marklogic Corbs

Tags: marklogic, marklogic-corb

We have a 3 nodes ML cluster.

In order to make CoRB2 or MLCP work with it, there are two ways to configure it.

1. Use a load balancer (eg. F5) as the single host for CoRB connection.
   (Load balancer should be configured for that XCC port for that ML cluster environment.)
2. Follow below [link](https://github.com/marklogic-community/corb2/blob/master/README.md) to set up multiple XCC hosts to directly connect to the 3 nodes.

[image]

**Which way is recommended and why?**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A load balancer lets you hide the server-side details from the connecting clients but requires an extra thing to setup and manage. It's worth the headache to keep some flexibility for a long-term deployment.

But you just want to run something quickly? List the hosts at the client and go.

Comment: If you have a load balancer, use it. It’s easier to configure a single hostname/endpoint. The CoRB multi-host feature was intended to help people spread the load across hosts even when they didn’t have a load balancer, instead of being limited to what a single E node could process.